# DebugDiag Crash Rule Does Not Auto-Execute

Tags: c++, windows, dump, postmortem-debugging

I'm using DebugDiag for the first time, and I'm using it on Windows 7 x64.  I've created a crash rule for (x86) myprogram.exe, which is guaranteed to crash because I've coded it intentionally to crash with an "unknown exception (0xc0000417)".

I have windows ["startup and recovery" configured to capture mini-dumps](http://www.faultwire.com/solutions/using_debug_diagnostic.php#create_dump_file).  It works.  I've [adjusted registry entries to capture custom mini-dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It works.  Yes, I'm getting two different dump files as a consequence.  It's ok by me.

But if I understand correctly, DebugDiag should simply "jump to life" when the crash rule is triggered, but instead DebugDiag does nothing when the crash happens.  DebugDiag only provides analysis if I explicitly load a dmp file manually into it.  What do I need to do to make the rule auto-trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using version 1.1 of DebugDiag.

I'm afraid it is not fully functional on Windows 7.
In version 1.1, the analysis-only version is installed and leak-tracking and dump generation does not work.

If you plan to generate dumps on application crash, you can use ProcDump from SysInternals with -e -ma flags.

DebugDiag 1.2 is available since july. You can download the packages from this [page](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26798).